# Getting the same error "inflating class TextView" only for the Nexus 5X

Tags: android, nexus-5

My app is currently live and on one specific device, the Nexus 5X there is the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kaisergames.guessIt/com.kaisergames.guessIt.LoginRegistration.SignInActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class TextView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I know there are some solutions to this problem but I checked all of them and nothing worked. I also cannot reproduce this error on the 5X emulator. On all other devices this error does not come up. The line #93 is the second TextView of the xml file, so there should be a problem in my xml file. There is a dimen value of the text size called @dimen/text_small_size, but this is defined in all my dimen files:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_sign_in"
    style="@style/AppBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_login"
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/guess_it"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo_log_in"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/guess_it" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_login_email"
            style="@style/CardViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#C20E14">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_login_mail"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_login_email"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_login_email"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_login_email"
                    style="@style/TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_login_mail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:text="Mit E-Mail anmelden"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_login_facebook"
            style="@style/CardViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#3C5A99">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_login_facebook"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_login_facebook"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_login_facebook"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_login_facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_login_facebook"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/actor"
                    android:text="Mit Facebook anmelden"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/login_google"
            style="@style/CardViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_login_google"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_login_google"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_login_google"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_brand" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextView"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_login_google"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_login_google"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/actor"
                    android:text="Mit Google anmelden"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All the dimens files are present as they should be.

I have the dimens.xml, dimens.xml (hdpi), dimens.xml (xhdpi), dimens.xml (xxhdpi).

I hope somebody can give me a hint to the solution.